# Flask session values are not saved on different requests

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have searched for solutions everywhere but couldn't solve my problem.
I am currently running a Flask application with uWSGI and NGINX in AWS.

My flask app is running locally `127.0.0.1:5000`.
I have tried adding `secret_key` as mentioned in different questions but it didn't work.

Here are some of my code:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, session, abort
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = 'filesystem'
app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = '/var/www/test/session'

Session(app)

@app.route('/auth/login', methods=['POST'], strict_slashes=False)
def login():
    # did some validations here
    session.permanent = True
    session['is_logged_in'] = True
    return redirect(url_for('home'))

@app.route('/auth/home', methods=['GET'], strict_slashes=False)
def home():
    if session.get('is_logged_in') == None:
        return redirect('/') # will return to default page
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I always get redirected to the default page since the `session` did not store 'is_logged_in' value. But it did store `{ permanent: True }` which I believe is from the line `session.permanent = True`.

Configuration in **nginx.conf**:

```
location /auth {
    rewrite ^/(.+) $1 break;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off:
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

If it helps, my uWSGI is running in `socket = 120.0.0.1:5000` and I am using `protocol = http`.

And when I checked application cookies in browser, it has a `session` cookie registered.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `if session['is_logged_in'] == False`

And set the session is logged as false in the start. On the top after `Session(app)` add this `session['is_logged_in'] = False`

Edit:

You check if 'logged_in' is present in session. 
When logging in do this:

```
if 'logged_in' in session:
    #User logged in
```

In logout do this

```
session.pop('logged_in')
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. That gave me a `RuntimeError: Working outside of request context`. I can only interact with sessions within an active HTTP request

Comment: Edited answer pls check

Comment: Hello, thank you again. My issue is that the values I set in `session` isn't saved when I move on to a different request. `is_logged_in` is never present in the session

Comment: You can use my method of you are trying to log the user in.

Comment: I am trying to make the sessions work. Since `is_logged_in` is never present in the session, `if 'is_logged_in' in session:` will never go through..

Comment: Also try removing the app.config lines with session params

Answer (score 0):

After some tedious research, it turns out I just needed to include `plugin = python36` in my **uwsgi.ini** which is from `uwsgi-plugin-python36` (rpm).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a lack of session persistence in my OAuth 2.0 flow. The SAMESITE ="Strict" setting was what was causing it.
In one of the steps the Identity Provider was failing to set cookie and respond with the same session id. This led to a new session being created at the end of the auth flow - hence no authentication was happening.

Setting SAMESITE to "Lax" solved my problem.